# subview user interaction disabled on UIViewController on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios7.1

I have `.xib` file in my app. I inserted the `.xib` file as subview to the viewController. I have user interaction is enabled, and on iOS 8 it works just as expected but then when I run my app on iOS 7 User Interaction is not working.

Comment: Did you try on device with the same screen size ?

Comment: Yes I tried. Unfortunately It is  iOS version issue.

Comment: Do you have a view introspection tool, like Reveal? That can reveal misconfigured views or event-sucking views that you didn't even know existed. The built in Xcode 6 introspection tool is worth a look too.

Answer (score 2):

Check in attribute inspector, user interaction enabled checked or not.

Comment: I would suggest then running your app on a physical device (both iOS 7 & 8) and say the results. If you can't then it may be a bug in xcode.